# OpenCV: Detect face using Haar Cascades and record video at the same time

Tags: opencv, video, detect, video-recording, sametime

As my title, can I detect face using Haar Cascades and record video at the same time?

I am using OpenCV to detect face by Haar Cascades, but I also want to record video during the detection process. Help me!

thank in advance!

Comment: where's the problem? One possible problem is the detection speed which might be too slow for live recording. In that case it might be good to separate detection and capturing in different threads.

Comment: I use JavaCameraView for detection, it is ok. And now, i don't know how to record video

Answer (score 0):

You can use VideoWriter class to record the video. Here is the [reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html).